# modify carbon based products and use mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, wso2

all. I hope it's not a wired dev-user case. just a simple scenario,if developers want to insert a jsp in AS, the configs (like how to link to the jsp) is set. In the jsp, he wants to create a form and a button. with filling the form and the button click. the data is persisted to mysql. But my question is, how to config MYSQL in the osgi and carbon based manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a MYSQL datasource configuration in to master-datasourcew.xml file and refer that configuration in your code. Also you want to add MYSQL JDBC library in to the AS server as it is not shipped by default. Then it should work. I have implemented similar sample. You can find it [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/03/06/xacml-sample-for-health-care/). I deploy a web service (called "MediCom Web Service") in WSO2AS, and it writes and read data from MYSQL database. Please go through sample code and the configuration. Hope this would help you.

Comment: yeah, I got your sample, It helps a bucket :) so does it make sense in the same way to use mysql when modifying the carbon base product?

Comment: By default carbon server is running with H2 database.. (this database used to store meta data and permission and so on..) where you can modify it to use MYSQL as well. You just need to edit the default configuration of "master-datasourcew.xml".  Also if you are trying the sample, you may need to deploy web app in tomcat and so on... you can just deploy the web service in WSO2AS and invoke web service using web service client such as SOAPUI

Comment: Thank you Asela. So according to your suggestion, may I consider it as 'if I want to create a db to store my new data, I can add a datasource in master-datasourece.xml and connect to this datasource'? But how? Using the same code in the sample seems I have to change the connection model in my legency webapp. any easier way out? :)

Comment: If you want to add new data (new tables), you want can use same  database that is used by the WSO2 Product...else you can create new database. (then you can add new datasource configuration in to master-datasouce file).  However you want to write code to persist and read data as it is specific to your custom data.  Here, you can create the database connection in a simple way...   (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/NAME-OF-CONFIG").getConnection;

Comment: thanks for your response! I will try and get you the feedback if I have farther issue. :D